# One DynamoDB client per service or one DynamoDB client for all services

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I have a .NET Core Web API that aggregates data from several tables in my DynamoDB.

There are 5 services that read from a related table (Think customer service, reads from customer table). Each service has it's own DynamoDB client and the services get executed concurrently.

I am having some issues under load. Basically every now and again a service takes a lot longer to complete its dynamo request. Usually each request is < 50ms but under concurrent load some requests can take up to 1 second.

I am reproducing this with a load test of 2000 req over period of 45 seconds (~44 req per sec).

My question is, is this the right design when querying multiple tables? Or should there only be one DynamoDB client doing all the queries? I know DynamoDB client uses HttpClient under the bonnet. Would this be the bottleneck?

As a side note, the SLAs are usually < 100ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Try to use `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100)` before doing any calls to DynamoDb. One client per service is OK in your case.

### Long answer

There is nothing wrong with using multiple clients only if your services accessing different tables. Every first call to a new table requires a synchronous `DescribeTable` call to populate caches, so you don't want it to happen multiple times for the same table. Overall, it's safer to use a single client for all services.

However, the official DynamoDB SDK for .net is very poor in performance and thread management, which most likely causing issues for you. There are some locks and sync operations besides `DescribeTable` that might cause thread starvation in some cases. You can try to "fix" it by setting `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100)` (you may want to use another reasonably big value instead of `100`). More details about [this issue on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1476)